# Application wide data context

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

This is more of a theory question than anything else, can't really show much in the way of code. However the topic is C# WPF.

So I have an application beginning with a main menu where I set a bunch of variables and load in some data from files and so on ready to begin the main program. I want this to be available to the main window that is going to be opened up.

Currently in my application I have it all set up by data context, an attempt at MVVM which I am very new to. This data context is linked to the menu window and allows me to set all the necessary data.

But how do I go about making that available to the new window. As far as I am aware a new data context is like a new object but in xaml, so if I were to create a data context in the next window all the information from it would be different?

I have always had trouble with things like this in all my learning of programming, I have data in one place but there is no sound way to link it across multiple windows/classes/objects etc.

Currently I have 4 files:

> 1 Holding all the data classes
>
> 2 My 'ViewModel' where I have the objects of these classes, property
>   updates, not too much
>
> 3 My menu with the bindings and data context and its code behind which is empty apart from some button
>   clicks
>
> 4 The main window that is going to use the data <-- this is my problem

First of all is this a correct approach, is there something different I should be thinking about? Can I implement a data context across two windows?

So I set up the context in the mainmenu window:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:WindowFunction x:Name="Interface"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And this links in my between file which has objects of the data.

```
class WindowFunction
{
    protected PortInfo settings = new PortInfo();
    protected FileInfo import = new FileInfo();
    protected ObservableCollection<PersonName> lanes = new ObservableCollection<PersonName>();

    public ObservableCollection<PersonName> Lane
    {
        get { return lanes; }
        set { lanes = value; }
    }

    public PortInfo Settings
    {
        get { return settings; }
        set { settings = value; }
    }

    public FileInfo Import
    {
        get { return import; }
        set { import = value; }
    }

}
```

I want to be able to call the information from this in another window. But if  I create a new context the property paths will be pointing somewhere else surely?

Comment: If by window you mean page you can use the rootFrame.DataContext. The frame is the same for all the pages you load in. If you really mean windows then i don't know

Comment: Can you post some example of what you're trying to do, or where you're getting confused?

Comment: No, it's two separate windows. One where I essentially have a form to set lots of data import files and so on, and the second where I'm wanting to display a lot of stuff. I'll try add something up.

Comment: Helps, but could you add what WindowFunction/Interface is doing?

Comment: ...and where do you make the new window? (sorry, I probably should have just asked for all this up front)

Comment: Thats just on a button press in the code behind of the menu. I'm probably doing it completely wrong anyway

Comment: Something like `Window dialog = new Window(); dialog.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: yeah, thing is, I couldn't send the data through at the same time because it needs to update on its own, which is why I felt the need for a wider ranging data context

Comment: Just an aside. If you're trying to do MVVM, I'd seriously look into Caliburn. It makes MVVM very easy to do.